# What is your react-i18next i18n key best practice? natural vs. keybased catalog?

Tags: internationalization, react-i18next

what is your [react-i18next](https://react.i18next.com/) i18n key best practice, [« natural vs. keybased catalog »](https://react.i18next.com/legacy-v9/step-by-step-guide#3-sidequest-natural-vs-keybased-catalog) ?

For now, I use only one namespace with natural english keybased catalog.

I intend to refactor my application to this structure:

- one namespace by page
- use keybased catalog

For instance, from:

```
<label>{t('firstname')}</label>
```

to

```
<label>{t('signin:signin-form.firstname')}</label>
```

and you, what is your best practice to i18n your front application?

Comment: GitLab use natural catalog https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/blob/master/locale/fr/gitlab.po